# Temp variable inside a loop with Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Vue + Vuetify, where I'm trying to build a menu with links using [treeview component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/).

The source is a nested json, and my problem is that I want to join the parent "to" with its children "to", this way I would have a full path to navigate, e.g.: link2/link3

**JSON:**

```
items: [
{
  id: 1,
  level: 1,
  name: 'link 1',
  children: [],
  to: 'link1',
},
{
  id: 2,
  level: 1,
  name: 'link2',
  to: 'link2',
  children: [
    { id: 3, level: 2, name: 'link 3', to: 'link3' },
    {
      id: 4,
      level: 2,
      name: 'link 4',
      to: 'link4',
      children: [
        { id: 5, level: 3, name: 'link 5', to: 'link5'},
        { id: 6, level: 3, name: 'link 5', to: 'link5'},
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

]

My tree view:

```
<v-treeview
  :items="items"
  item-key="name"
  dense
  hoverable
  open-on-click
  hide-details="true"
>
  <template
    slot="label"
    slot-scope="{ item }"
  >
    <nuxt-link
      :to="buildLink(item)"
      class="menu-item"
    >
      {{ item.name }}
    </nuxt-link>
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```

Vue code:

```
export default {
 data () {
   return {
     urlPath: [],
   }
 },
 methods: {
   buildLink (item) {
    const level = item.level - 1
    if (level > this.urlPath.length) {
      this.urlPath.push(item.to)
    } else if (level - 1 < this.urlPath.length) {
      this.urlPath.splice(
        level,
        this.urlPath.length - level,
        item.to,
      )
    } else if (level === this.urlPath.length) {
      this.urlPath[this.urlPath.length - 1] = item.to
    }
    return this.urlPath.join('/')
  },
},
 }
}
```

This code almost worked, meaning, the menu appears, but the error `You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function` and that is because I'm changing data inside my method. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: where are you using urlPath?

Comment: Inside buildLink method. I use as a temp variable to keep the path from the parent when the treeview reads the children data, so I can join the parent e child path to form a link.

Comment: So there's no good reason for it to be `data`? I guess that's the answer.

Comment: Ok, so how can I use a temp variable without vue's reactivity? The way I did it, I need something outside my method to store the previews value.

Comment: please clarify more your use case, i think we could have a better solution

Comment: My goal is a menu exactly like this https://flutter.dev/docs (left). I'm learning Vue, so, if there is another way to do it, i'm all on board!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can achieve this by simply using recursion. You can set append links using the example below:

```
var items = [
{
  id: 1,
  level: 1,
  name: 'link 1',
  children: [],
  to: 'link1',
},
{
  id: 2,
  level: 1,
  name: 'link2',
  to: 'link2',
  children: [
    { id: 3, level: 2, name: 'link 3', to: 'link3' },
    {
      id: 4,
      level: 2,
      name: 'link 4',
      to: 'link4',
      children: [
        { id: 5, level: 3, name: 'link 5', to: 'link5'},
        { id: 6, level: 3, name: 'link 5', to: 'link5'},
      ],
    }
  ]
}
];


const getItems = () => {
this.items = this.items.map(x=> {
    if(x.children && x.children.length) {
    x.children = getPopulatedChildren(x.children, x.to);
  }
  return x;
});
console.log(this.items);
return this.items;
}
```

Option 1: If you want to combine the link with parent only. For example for link 5 it would be something like **link4/link5** then getPopulatedChildren would be

```
const getPopulatedChildren = (children, to) => {
  return children.map(x=> {
    if(x.children && x.children.length) {
      x.children = getPopulatedChildren(x.children, x.to);
    }
    return {...x, to: to+'/'+x.to}; 
  });
}
```

Option 2: If you want to combine the link with all the parents. For example for link 5 it would be something like **link2/link4/link5** then getPopulatedChildren would be

```
const getPopulatedChildren = (children, to) => {
    return children.map(x=> {
    x.to = to+'/'+x.to;
    if(x.children && x.children.length) {
        x.children = getPopulatedChildren(x.children, x.to);
    }
    return x; 
  });
}
```

Make sure to update the Tree view and call getItems function to get the Items with updated link

```
<v-treeview
  :items="getItems()"
  item-key="name"
  dense
  hoverable
  open-on-click
  hide-details="true"
>
  <template
    slot="label"
    slot-scope="{ item }"
  >
    <nuxt-link
      :to="item.to"
      class="menu-item"
    >
      {{ item.name }}
    </nuxt-link>
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```